# A random picturebox won't move when coded in Timer

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, picturebox

I don't know if  I still have missing on this but whenever you want to add PictureBox, you just find it on Toolbox and drag it on the UI. But what I did is I coded it by adding PictureBox then what I want is I have to move it to the right. I coded it on a Timer and this is how I do.

```
 private void enemyMove_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GameMenu menu = new GameMenu();

        if (menu.cmbox_Level.Text.Equals("Easy"))
        {

            this.Controls.Add(menu.EnemyTank);
            menu.EnemyTank.Width = 26;
            menu.EnemyTank.Height = 32;
            menu.EnemyTank.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Tank_RIGHT_v_2;
            menu.EnemyTank.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
            menu.EnemyTank.Left += 2;
        }
    }
```

Don't ask me if the Timer is started. Yes it already started, it was coded on the Form. But somehow when I start the program it doesn't move. But then I tried adding PictureBox, this time I tried dragging it to UI then add an Image on it, then coded it by moving to the right. When I start the program it works. But what I want is that whenever I start the button it will just make the random PictureBox move to the right. Idk what's the missing in here.

Comment: Is `this` a winform?

Comment: It looks like you're adding the same "EnemyTank" to `Controls` over and over. Why?

Comment: Yes sorry if this doesn't related to Unity or something. I was trying to make a game using Winforms.

Comment: @John Nope, I'm only coding its properties like the Size, Background Image and the Layout. I only added it once.

Comment: Again, you could look at it closely. I only added a PictureBox once then code its Properties. also how do you think that the Timer is called 20 times? What I was doing is that I want to move the PictureBox to the right with its timer.

Comment: Is a new `GameMenu` always contains a new `EnemyTank`? I would assume yes.  If every new `GameMenu` create its own `EnemyTank`, `EnemyTank.Left +=2` is always the same, which is the default value +2. Use breakpoint to check value change of `EnemyTank.Left`. Post your `GameMenu` would help people answer your question.

Comment: For everytime that the EnemyTank gets killed. It will Respawn with no limits. And as I was doing I want to make the Tank move. using its Timer. However it doesn't even work after I start the program.

Answer (score 0):

I made some assumptions. If I my assumptions aren't correct, please update your post for details. Following content is copied from my comment.

1. A new `GameMenu` will always create a new `EnemyTank`.
2. A `EnemyTank`'s default `Left` value is fixed;

Your `enemyMove_Tick` is keep creating `GameMenu` and `EnemyTank`.
That is, every tick, a `EnemyTank` is created and value changed to "default value plus 2" in your code.

To avoid it, you have to keep `EnemyTank` instance somewhere instead of keep creating it.

Here's a example.

```
 GameMenu m_menu;

 void YourConstructor()
    {
            //  InitializeComponent();
            //  something else in your form constructor
            m_menu = new GameMenu();

            m_menu.EnemyTank.Width = 26;
            m_menu.EnemyTank.Height = 32;
            m_menu.EnemyTank.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Tank_RIGHT_v_2;
            m_menu.EnemyTank.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
            this.Controls.Add( m_menu.EnemyTank );
    }
 private void enemyMove_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (menu.cmbox_Level.Text.Equals("Easy"))
        {
            m_menu.EnemyTank.Left += 2;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well adding picturebox is not a problem. The only thing problem is that it doesn't move. the code `private void enemyMove_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (menu.cmbox_Level.Text.Equals("Easy"))
        {
            m_menu.EnemyTank.Left += 2;
        }
    }`

Means to go right that's why I put it on Timer to be able to move once I call it on the Form to start the time.

Comment: From the Game Menu if the ComboBox has been selected the difficulty as Easy, then it will add a PictureBox on the Game. That goes the same as the other Diffculty level.

Comment: @MineDyse Do you mean `if (menu.cmbox_Level.Text.Equals("Easy"))` this statement would be only true once? Other tick doesn't pass through this statement? Then where is the code you actually set `m_menu.EnemyTank.Left += 2`? Because your code does it just once.

Comment: @MineDyse "Well adding picturebox is not a problem. The only thing problem is that it doesn't move. " This is not what I mean, the actual problem is you always create a new PictureBox and set its value +=2. I assume that's why you never see it move.

Comment: @MineDyse Could you post the code about the constructor of `GameMenu` and `EnemyTank`?